# Is there a way to show the IDE which Type of Objects are in a List, so it colors / autocompletes properly?

Tags: python, list, ide

I recognize from c# that you could do

`(int)(randomVariable + 1 + anythingElse)`

and the IDE would understand that the named variable/result is an integer.

Now in Python I want to let my IDE know, that in the list ceDocs which I am sending as a parameter will be objects of the class Doc so I can use autocomplete and proper coloring instead of "any" everywhere.

```
def createDocuments(ceDocs):
    for doc in ceDocs:
        doc.name = doc.path # example action

createDocuments(getFromPath(path))
```

Is there a way to do this in python?

Please correct me if this makes no sense... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use type hints with the [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module.

```
from typing import List

class Doc:
   # ...

def createDocuments(ceDocs: List[Doc]):
    for doc in ceDocs:
        doc.name = doc.path # example action
```

Answer (score 1):

For python 3.10:

```
def createDocuments(ceDocs: list[Doc]):
    for doc in ceDocs:
        doc.name = doc.path # example action
```

For earlier versions:

```
from typing import List

def createDocuments(ceDocs: List[Doc]):
    for doc in ceDocs:
        doc.name = doc.path # example action
```